# Can chrome://flags/#enable-force-dark make exceptions for certain websites?

Tags: google-chrome, dark-mode

While `chrome://flags/#enable-force-dark` ("Automatically render all web contents using a dark theme") is an interesting option, some websites simply aren't ready for it. For example, as hard as it might be to believe, Google's very own Gmail:

[image: Gmail's buttons in Dark Mode]

Since it's a shame not to use this in general because of this, is there a way to make exceptions for similar websites?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The description of the flag is clearly stating that it is for ALL tabs.

So the answer to your question is clearly No :)